# Code to automate a web form in SilkTest tool using VB/.NET Language?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, vbscript, .net, silktest

I am new to Silk test and dont know VB or .NET coding.

Please provide a sample code to automate a website/form in VB or .NET?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a free tutorial service.

Answer (score 2):

- The most comprehensive tutorials for Silk Test can be found in the Micro Focus web-based training, [check here in details](https://www.microfocus.com/ondemand/courses/silk-test-workbench-essentials-free/) (see chapter 14 for .NET scripting).
- In addition to that you can [check out the online documentation](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/topic/com.borland.silktest.workbench.doc/SILKTEST-EF820A00-CREATINGSCRIPTS-CON.html?cp=9_3_1_3_1) too.
- For general questions you can also use the [Silk Test Community Forum](https://community.microfocus.com/borland/test/silk_test/f/forum) and of-course Stack-overflow.

DISCLAIMER: I work for Micro Focus and am the Product Owner for Silk Test.